# como puedo crear una funcionalidad habilitar la edicion de una lista de elemento

Tags: javascript, angular, angular9

estoy intentando hacer algo como esto:

De una lista de elementos por ejemplo:

```
public propietarios = [{nombre: 'Juan'}, {nombre: 'Pedro'}]
public carros = [{marca: 'hiunday', propietario: 'Juan'}, {marca: 'hiunday', propietario: 'Pedro'}]
```

Quiero iterar en la vista y agregar la funcionalidad de editar; más o menos así:

```
<div *ngFor="let car of carros">
  <p>Marca: {{car.marca}}</p>
  <p class="jqueryCambiarPropietario">Propietario: 
<select>
<option value="">---select---</option>
<ng-container *ngFor="let p of propietarios">
<option value="{{p.id}}" [selected]="p.nombre == car.propietario">{{p.nombre}}
</option>
</ng-container>
</select>
<button class=" btn btn-success" (click)="cambiarPropietario(event)"> <i class="icon icon-save"></i> </button>
</select> 
</p>
</div>
```

Lo ideal sería que al dar clic en el botón, la función cambiarPropietario, efectúe el cambio en el backend enviando el nuevo valor seleccionado. Sin embargo me encuentro con varios problemas.

- El botón no está vinculado con el select:
  Intente encerrar la edición dentro de un formulario, pero no sé cómo referenciarlo dinámicamente en el componente.
- Intente colocar en el select un FormControl, pero no logro fijar el valor por defecto apropiado a cada elemento (Se fija el último valor de la lista).
- Tambie prove en solo colar un boton editar, y al presionar me cargue un componente justo debajo del mismo y me permita realizar la operación. Pero no sé cómo hacer esa carga dinamicamente.

*Con jquery, colocaría un sobre la clase jqueryCambiarPropietario, y cuando hiciera un click en el botón podría consultar por el valor seleccionado. Como consigo algo parecido en angular.

Estoy seguro de que angular tiene otro modo de trabajar y aún me falta revisar, agradezco desde ya algo que me oriente en este tema.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer es agregar una referencia a la option activa/seleccionada de tu select, eso te permitirá que al dar click en el botón, pases la como parámetro la referencia de option activa.

Así:

```
<div *ngFor="let car of carros">
<p>Marca: {{car.marca}}</p>
<p class="jqueryCambiarPropietario">Propietario: 

    <select>
        <option value="">---select---</option>
        <ng-container *ngFor="let p of propietarios">
            <option #opcionSeleccionada value="{{p.id}}" [selected]="p.nombre == car.propietario">{{p.nombre}}</option>
        </ng-container>
    </select>

    <button class=" btn btn-success" (click)="cambiarPropietario(opcionSeleccionada.value)"> 
        <i class="icon icon-save"></i> 
    </button>
</select> 
</p>
```

Saludos, espero te sirva!.